# JSON with locations to a dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have this json file that contains the distance and the travel duration between one point to another one. For instance, below I have the distances from the depot to the depot, and then the depot to A. And again, from A to the depot, and then from A to A.

```json
json_data = '''
{
    "depot": [
                        {
                            "destinationIndex": 0,
                            "originIndex": 0,
                            "totalWalkDuration": 0,
                            "travelDistance": 0,
                            "travelDuration": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "destinationIndex": 0,
                            "originIndex": 0,
                            "totalWalkDuration": 0,
                            "travelDistance": 39.025,
                            "travelDuration": 30.4167
                        }
                    ],
    "A": [
                        {
                            "destinationIndex": 0,
                            "originIndex": 0,
                            "totalWalkDuration": 0,
                            "travelDistance": 39.128,
                            "travelDuration": 31.9
                        },
                        {
                            "destinationIndex": 1,
                            "originIndex": 0,
                            "totalWalkDuration": 0,
                            "travelDistance": 0,
                            "travelDuration": 0
                        }
                    ]
}
'''
```

What I would like to have is a distance matrix. As I have more than 350 locations, I want to loop over the file to create a distance matrix like in this example:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 39.025 |
| 39.128 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC your distance matrix should be symetric.
You can use `json_normalize` on your dictionary values:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.loads(json_data)
locs = data.keys()
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(val)['travelDistance'] for val in data.values()], axis=1)
df.index = locs
df.columns = locs
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        depot       A
depot   0.000  39.128
A      39.025   0.000
```